# How to use SSRS Expression

Tags: c#, regex, html-encode

I am using expression to replace text as follow:

```
RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;Test&gt;", @"&(.|\n)*?;", " ");
```

which give result  `Test`   But i want `result <Test>`.

Comment: Do you mean literally `result`? Or do you mean the whole match? Or what you captured?

Comment: i want  &lt;Test&gt; in result

Comment: what about [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply this?

```
string result = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input).Trim();
```

Leave out the `Trim` if you want to keep those spaces.